# Failure running log2timeline/plaso container in GCP Batch service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Im trying to run the following container in GCP's Batch service:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/log2timeline/plaso

Using the following Runnable config:

```
        "runnables": [
          {
            "container": {
              "imageUri": "log2timeline/plaso",
              "entrypoint": "",
              "commands": [
                "log2timeline.py",
                "--storage_file /dataout/file1.plaso",
                "/datain/hostfiles"
              ],
              "volumes": [
                "/tmp/processed:/dataout",
                "/tmp:/datain"
              ]
            }
          }
```

Results in the following error message:

- log2timeline.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /datain/hostfiles

The working command is as follows:

`docker run -v /Localdrive/:/data log2timeline/plaso log2timeline.py --storage-file /data/jm1.plaso /data/hostfiles`

Here is the reference for the Batch container object:

- https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/batch/latest/google.cloud.batch_v1.types.Runnable.Container

I have tried various combinations of configs but all failed. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Fixed it by splitting the args up in the "commands" section.
          
"commands": [
                "log2timeline.py",
                "--storage_file",
                "/dataout/file1.plaso",
                "/datain/hostfiles"
],

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this issue was resolved based on https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Infrastructure-Compute-Storage/Docker-command-failing-in-Batch-Service/m-p/614749#M3815